# Class inheritance for compatibility across application versions?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm considering the possibility of implementing, on top of the C++ class inheritance, file compatibility across different application versions (for example: opening in **myapp 2.0** a file saved from **myapp 1.0**).

Let's suppose for example that **myapp 1.0** has a:

```
class employee {
   public:
      char *mp_name;
      unsigned int m_age;

      (and all needed serialization methods)
}
```

Next you develop **myapp 2.0** which adds support for salaries, but instead of modifying the classes in 1.0, you derive new classes:

```
class employee20: public employee {
   public:
      unsigned int m_salary;

      (methods for creating employee20 from employee and viceversa)
      (and all needed serialization methods)
}
```

With this mechanism, it seems one could get easy compatibility for reading **myapp 1.0** files from **myapp 2.0**, and even being able to save 1.0 files from the 2.0 version, because `employee20` has methods for creating one object from another in a different version.

But now, let's suppose you release **myapp 3.0** which **drops support for the employees age**...

Is it possible to remove a inherited member from a derived class?

I mean, is it possible to do something like this:

```
class employee30: public employee20 {
   public:
      void m_age;

      (methods for creating employee30 from employee20 and viceversa)
      (and all needed serialization methods)
}
```

Or maybe there's no way for accomplishing this, and it just shows that I should abandon the idea of getting version compatibility through inheritance?

Comment: Looks like `factory  design pattern` will suit your requirement.

Comment: Beside of the fact that a member variable may not be of type `void`, this wouldn't discard the inherited member of same name (just somehow eclipse it a bit).

Comment: inheritance is not what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because you are mixing class design with application input/output. They are separate. Class inheritance is for defining internal objects. Input/output is for external application data.

A good approach is to have a saver/loader class. This way data is decoupled from the actual implementation. When things change, the save/load class is the only one handling compatibility.